# Calculate $\int x(x+1)^{1/2} dx$.

Tags: calculus

The integral in question:

> $$I=\int x(x+1)^{1/2} dx$$

I've done integration by parts to get to
$I=x\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2} - \int\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2} dx$.
I've used *mathematica* and for the integral $\int \frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2} dx$ when I calculate it by hand, I get $\frac{4}{15}(x+1)^{5/2}$ but apparently it should be just $\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{5/2}$. I think something is wrong with my arithmetic. I thought $\int x^ndx = x^{n+1}/(n+1)$ which, in my case, I thought it would be $n+1=\frac{5}{2}$, $\frac{2}{3}\colon\frac{5}{2} = 4/15$. Therefore $I=\frac{4}{15}(x+1)^{5/2}$.

Comment: No, you're correct. Essentially $\int u^n \, du$ is found by raising the power by $1$, and dividing by your new power. My guess is you input it wrong into whatever you used to solve it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Try learning a little bit of $\LaTeX$ in order to be able to use the site correctly. It is considered almost necessary on this site to have an explicit question that you want to be answered, try something like "where did I go wrong?" for this type of question. This will reduce the downvotes and increase the chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Don't forget $+C$!!!

Comment: Another approach is to write $$x(1+x)^{1/2}=(1+x)^{3/2}-(1+x)^{1/2}$$ and both of those are easy to integrate.

Comment: You are correct. You forgot the first term. $\frac 23x(1+x)^{3/2}$ and the minus sign infront of the $4/5$ term

Comment: Depending on your preference, you may represent the integral result in different ways:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{3}x(1+x)^{3/2} - \frac{4}{15}(1+x)^{5/2}
&= \frac{2}{3}x(1+x)^{3/2} - \frac{4}{15}(1+x)(1+x)^{3/2}\\
&= \frac{2}{5}x(1+x)^{3/2} - \frac{4}{15}(1+x)^{3/2}\\
&= \frac{2}{5}(1+x)^{5/2} - \frac{2}{3}(1+x)^{3/2}&+C
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

I use $$\begin{align} x\sqrt{1+x}&=(1+x)\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+x}\\&=(1+x)^{3/2}-(1+x)^{1/2}.\end{align} $$ With the right side easily integrated to give (ignoring the constant:)

$$\begin{align} \frac25(1+x)^{5/2}-\frac23(1+x)^{3/2}&=\left(\frac25(1+x)-\frac23\right)(1+x)^{3/2}\\&=\left(\frac25x-\frac4{15}\right)(1+x)^{3/2}\end{align} $$

Your answer is: $$\begin{align} \frac23x(1+x)^{3/2}-\frac4{15}(1+x)^{5/2}&=\left(\frac23x-\frac4{15}(1+x)\right)(1+x)^{3/2}\\&=\left(\frac25x-\frac4{15}\right)(1+x)^{3/2} \end{align} $$

Same answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to do this using the substitution $u=x+1$. Then
$$I=\int(u-1)u^{\frac12}du=\frac25u^{5/2}-\frac23u^{3/2}+C,$$
where $C$ is the constant of integration.

Substitute back for $x$ in this to get
$$
I=(1+x)^{3/2}\left(\frac25(1+x)-\frac23\right)+C=(1+x)^{3/2}\left(\frac25 x - {4\over 15}\right)+C
$$
No matter how you wangle it, there isn't a term of the form $\frac23(1+x)^{5/2}$ here, so whereever you got that from is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\sqrt{x+1}$ and then
$$ x=u^2-1, dx=2udu. $$
so
$$I=\int x(x+1)^{1/2} dx=2\int(u^2-1)u^2du=\frac25u^5-\frac23u^3+C=\frac25(x+1)^{5/2}-\frac23(x+1)^{3/2}+C.$$